# Event not firing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, combobox

I'm somewhat new to JavaScript. I'm using a grid control called Spread and in that grid I have three rows and three columns of comboboxes. I also have a native ASP textbox. What I want is to display the value of the combobox, once it has been changed by the client, in the textbox. To do this I'm using a DataChanged event of the Spread control.
However, nothing happens when I run this locally and change a value in any of Spread's combobox.

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <FarPoint:FpSpread ID="FpSpread1" runat="server" ActiveSheetViewIndex="0" 
    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
    DesignString="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;Spread /&gt;" 
    Height="200px" Width="400px">
    <ClientEvents DataChanged="dataChanged" />
    <commandbar backcolor="Control" buttonfacecolor="Control" 
        buttonhighlightcolor="ControlLightLight" buttonshadowcolor="ControlDark">
        <Background BackgroundImageUrl="SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/cbbg.gif">
        </Background>
    </commandbar>
    <Pager Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" 
        Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
    <HierBar Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" 
        Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
    <sheets>
        <FarPoint:SheetView DesignString="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;Sheet&gt;&lt;Data&gt;&lt;RowHeader class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetDataModel&quot; rows=&quot;3&quot; columns=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoCalculation&gt;True&lt;/AutoCalculation&gt;&lt;AutoGenerateColumns&gt;True&lt;/AutoGenerateColumns&gt;&lt;ReferenceStyle&gt;A1&lt;/ReferenceStyle&gt;&lt;Iteration&gt;False&lt;/Iteration&gt;&lt;MaximumIterations&gt;1&lt;/MaximumIterations&gt;&lt;MaximumChange&gt;0.001&lt;/MaximumChange&gt;&lt;/RowHeader&gt;&lt;ColumnHeader class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetDataModel&quot; rows=&quot;1&quot; columns=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoCalculation&gt;True&lt;/AutoCalculation&gt;&lt;AutoGenerateColumns&gt;True&lt;/AutoGenerateColumns&gt;&lt;ReferenceStyle&gt;A1&lt;/ReferenceStyle&gt;&lt;Iteration&gt;False&lt;/Iteration&gt;&lt;MaximumIterations&gt;1&lt;/MaximumIterations&gt;&lt;MaximumChange&gt;0.001&lt;/MaximumChange&gt;&lt;/ColumnHeader&gt;&lt;DataArea class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetDataModel&quot; rows=&quot;3&quot; columns=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoCalculation&gt;True&lt;/AutoCalculation&gt;&lt;AutoGenerateColumns&gt;True&lt;/AutoGenerateColumns&gt;&lt;ReferenceStyle&gt;A1&lt;/ReferenceStyle&gt;&lt;Iteration&gt;False&lt;/Iteration&gt;&lt;MaximumIterations&gt;1&lt;/MaximumIterations&gt;&lt;MaximumChange&gt;0.001&lt;/MaximumChange&gt;&lt;SheetName&gt;Sheet1&lt;/SheetName&gt;&lt;Cells&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;0&quot; column=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;Pippo&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;0&quot; column=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;din&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;0&quot; column=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;a&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;1&quot; column=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;pippo&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;1&quot; column=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;din&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;1&quot; column=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;a&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;2&quot; column=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;pippo&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;2&quot; column=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;din&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;2&quot; column=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.String&quot;&gt;a&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;/Cells&gt;&lt;/DataArea&gt;&lt;SheetCorner class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetDataModel&quot; rows=&quot;1&quot; columns=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoCalculation&gt;True&lt;/AutoCalculation&gt;&lt;AutoGenerateColumns&gt;True&lt;/AutoGenerateColumns&gt;&lt;ReferenceStyle&gt;A1&lt;/ReferenceStyle&gt;&lt;Iteration&gt;False&lt;/Iteration&gt;&lt;MaximumIterations&gt;1&lt;/MaximumIterations&gt;&lt;MaximumChange&gt;0.001&lt;/MaximumChange&gt;&lt;/SheetCorner&gt;&lt;ColumnFooter class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetDataModel&quot; rows=&quot;1&quot; columns=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoCalculation&gt;True&lt;/AutoCalculation&gt;&lt;AutoGenerateColumns&gt;True&lt;/AutoGenerateColumns&gt;&lt;ReferenceStyle&gt;A1&lt;/ReferenceStyle&gt;&lt;Iteration&gt;False&lt;/Iteration&gt;&lt;MaximumIterations&gt;1&lt;/MaximumIterations&gt;&lt;MaximumChange&gt;0.001&lt;/MaximumChange&gt;&lt;/ColumnFooter&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;Presentation&gt;&lt;AxisModels&gt;&lt;Column class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetAxisModel&quot; orientation=&quot;Horizontal&quot; count=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item index=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;&lt;SortIndicator&gt;Ascending&lt;/SortIndicator&gt;&lt;/Item&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/Column&gt;&lt;RowHeaderColumn class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetAxisModel&quot; defaultSize=&quot;40&quot; orientation=&quot;Horizontal&quot; count=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item index=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;&lt;SortIndicator&gt;Ascending&lt;/SortIndicator&gt;&lt;Size&gt;40&lt;/Size&gt;&lt;/Item&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/RowHeaderColumn&gt;&lt;ColumnHeaderRow class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetAxisModel&quot; defaultSize=&quot;22&quot; orientation=&quot;Vertical&quot; count=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item index=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;&lt;Size&gt;22&lt;/Size&gt;&lt;/Item&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/ColumnHeaderRow&gt;&lt;ColumnFooterRow class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetAxisModel&quot; defaultSize=&quot;22&quot; orientation=&quot;Vertical&quot; count=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item index=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;&lt;Size&gt;22&lt;/Size&gt;&lt;/Item&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/ColumnFooterRow&gt;&lt;/AxisModels&gt;&lt;StyleModels&gt;&lt;RowHeader class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetStyleModel&quot; Rows=&quot;3&quot; Columns=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;AltRowCount&gt;2&lt;/AltRowCount&gt;&lt;DefaultStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.NamedStyle&quot; Parent=&quot;RowHeaderDefault&quot; /&gt;&lt;ConditionalFormatCollections /&gt;&lt;/RowHeader&gt;&lt;ColumnHeader class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetStyleModel&quot; Rows=&quot;1&quot; Columns=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;AltRowCount&gt;2&lt;/AltRowCount&gt;&lt;DefaultStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.NamedStyle&quot; Parent=&quot;ColumnHeaderDefault&quot;&gt;&lt;Background class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Background&quot;&gt;&lt;BackgroundImageUrl&gt;SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/chbg.gif&lt;/BackgroundImageUrl&gt;&lt;SelectedBackgroundImageUrl&gt;SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/chm.png&lt;/SelectedBackgroundImageUrl&gt;&lt;/Background&gt;&lt;/DefaultStyle&gt;&lt;ConditionalFormatCollections /&gt;&lt;/ColumnHeader&gt;&lt;DataArea class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetStyleModel&quot; Rows=&quot;3&quot; Columns=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;AltRowCount&gt;2&lt;/AltRowCount&gt;&lt;DefaultStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.NamedStyle&quot; Parent=&quot;DataAreaDefault&quot; /&gt;&lt;ColumnStyles&gt;&lt;ColumnStyle Index=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;CellType class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.ComboBoxCellType&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoPostBack&gt;True&lt;/AutoPostBack&gt;&lt;ShowButton&gt;True&lt;/ShowButton&gt;&lt;UseValue&gt;True&lt;/UseValue&gt;&lt;OnClientChanged&gt;updatedcell&lt;/OnClientChanged&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;pippo&quot; value=&quot;pippo&quot; /&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;pluto&quot; value=&quot;pluto&quot; /&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;paperino&quot; value=&quot;paperino&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/CellType&gt;&lt;TabStop&gt;True&lt;/TabStop&gt;&lt;/ColumnStyle&gt;&lt;ColumnStyle Index=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;CellType class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.ComboBoxCellType&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoPostBack&gt;True&lt;/AutoPostBack&gt;&lt;ShowButton&gt;True&lt;/ShowButton&gt;&lt;UseValue&gt;True&lt;/UseValue&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;din&quot; value=&quot;din&quot; /&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;don&quot; value=&quot;don&quot; /&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;dan&quot; value=&quot;dan&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/CellType&gt;&lt;TabStop&gt;True&lt;/TabStop&gt;&lt;/ColumnStyle&gt;&lt;ColumnStyle Index=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;CellType class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.ComboBoxCellType&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoPostBack&gt;True&lt;/AutoPostBack&gt;&lt;ShowButton&gt;True&lt;/ShowButton&gt;&lt;UseValue&gt;True&lt;/UseValue&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;a&quot; value=&quot;a&quot; /&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;b&quot; value=&quot;b&quot; /&gt;&lt;Item text=&quot;c&quot; value=&quot;c&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/CellType&gt;&lt;TabStop&gt;True&lt;/TabStop&gt;&lt;/ColumnStyle&gt;&lt;/ColumnStyles&gt;&lt;CellStyles&gt;&lt;CellStyle Row=&quot;0&quot; Column=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;c class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.ComboBoxCellType&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;True&lt;/p&gt;&lt;s&gt;True&lt;/s&gt;&lt;u&gt;True&lt;/u&gt;&lt;h&gt;&lt;d t=&quot;Pippo&quot; v=&quot;pippo&quot; /&gt;&lt;d t=&quot;Pluto &quot; /&gt;&lt;d t=&quot;Paperino&quot; /&gt;&lt;/h&gt;&lt;/c&gt;&lt;ts&gt;True&lt;/ts&gt;&lt;/CellStyle&gt;&lt;/CellStyles&gt;&lt;ConditionalFormatCollections /&gt;&lt;/DataArea&gt;&lt;SheetCorner class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetStyleModel&quot; Rows=&quot;1&quot; Columns=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;AltRowCount&gt;2&lt;/AltRowCount&gt;&lt;DefaultStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.NamedStyle&quot; Parent=&quot;CornerDefault&quot;&gt;&lt;Background class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Background&quot;&gt;&lt;BackgroundImageUrl&gt;SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/chbg.gif&lt;/BackgroundImageUrl&gt;&lt;SelectedBackgroundImageUrl&gt;SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/chm.png&lt;/SelectedBackgroundImageUrl&gt;&lt;/Background&gt;&lt;/DefaultStyle&gt;&lt;ConditionalFormatCollections /&gt;&lt;/SheetCorner&gt;&lt;ColumnFooter class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetStyleModel&quot; Rows=&quot;1&quot; Columns=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;AltRowCount&gt;2&lt;/AltRowCount&gt;&lt;DefaultStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.NamedStyle&quot; Parent=&quot;ColumnFooterDefault&quot; /&gt;&lt;ConditionalFormatCollections /&gt;&lt;/ColumnFooter&gt;&lt;/StyleModels&gt;&lt;MessageRowStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Appearance&quot;&gt;&lt;BackColor&gt;LightYellow&lt;/BackColor&gt;&lt;ForeColor&gt;Red&lt;/ForeColor&gt;&lt;/MessageRowStyle&gt;&lt;SheetCornerStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.NamedStyle&quot; Parent=&quot;CornerDefault&quot;&gt;&lt;Background class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Background&quot;&gt;&lt;BackgroundImageUrl&gt;SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/chbg.gif&lt;/BackgroundImageUrl&gt;&lt;SelectedBackgroundImageUrl&gt;SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/chm.png&lt;/SelectedBackgroundImageUrl&gt;&lt;/Background&gt;&lt;/SheetCornerStyle&gt;&lt;AllowLoadOnDemand&gt;false&lt;/AllowLoadOnDemand&gt;&lt;LoadRowIncrement &gt;10&lt;/LoadRowIncrement &gt;&lt;LoadInitRowCount &gt;30&lt;/LoadInitRowCount &gt;&lt;AllowVirtualScrollPaging&gt;false&lt;/AllowVirtualScrollPaging&gt;&lt;TopRow&gt;0&lt;/TopRow&gt;&lt;PreviewRowStyle class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.PreviewRowInfo&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Presentation&gt;&lt;Settings&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Sheet1&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Categories&gt;&lt;Appearance&gt;&lt;GridLineColor&gt;#d0d7e5&lt;/GridLineColor&gt;&lt;SelectionBackColor&gt;#eaecf5&lt;/SelectionBackColor&gt;&lt;SelectionBorder class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Border&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Appearance&gt;&lt;Behavior&gt;&lt;EditTemplateColumnCount&gt;2&lt;/EditTemplateColumnCount&gt;&lt;GroupBarText&gt;Drag a column to group by that column.&lt;/GroupBarText&gt;&lt;/Behavior&gt;&lt;Layout&gt;&lt;ColumnHeaderRowCount&gt;1&lt;/ColumnHeaderRowCount&gt;&lt;RowHeaderColumnCount&gt;1&lt;/RowHeaderColumnCount&gt;&lt;/Layout&gt;&lt;/Categories&gt;&lt;ActiveRow&gt;0&lt;/ActiveRow&gt;&lt;ActiveColumn&gt;0&lt;/ActiveColumn&gt;&lt;ColumnHeaderRowCount&gt;1&lt;/ColumnHeaderRowCount&gt;&lt;ColumnFooterRowCount&gt;1&lt;/ColumnFooterRowCount&gt;&lt;PrintInfo&gt;&lt;Header /&gt;&lt;Footer /&gt;&lt;ZoomFactor&gt;0&lt;/ZoomFactor&gt;&lt;FirstPageNumber&gt;1&lt;/FirstPageNumber&gt;&lt;Orientation&gt;Auto&lt;/Orientation&gt;&lt;PrintType&gt;All&lt;/PrintType&gt;&lt;PageOrder&gt;Auto&lt;/PageOrder&gt;&lt;BestFitCols&gt;False&lt;/BestFitCols&gt;&lt;BestFitRows&gt;False&lt;/BestFitRows&gt;&lt;PageStart&gt;-1&lt;/PageStart&gt;&lt;PageEnd&gt;-1&lt;/PageEnd&gt;&lt;ColStart&gt;-1&lt;/ColStart&gt;&lt;ColEnd&gt;-1&lt;/ColEnd&gt;&lt;RowStart&gt;-1&lt;/RowStart&gt;&lt;RowEnd&gt;-1&lt;/RowEnd&gt;&lt;ShowBorder&gt;True&lt;/ShowBorder&gt;&lt;ShowGrid&gt;True&lt;/ShowGrid&gt;&lt;ShowColor&gt;True&lt;/ShowColor&gt;&lt;ShowColumnHeader&gt;Inherit&lt;/ShowColumnHeader&gt;&lt;ShowRowHeader&gt;Inherit&lt;/ShowRowHeader&gt;&lt;ShowColumnFooter&gt;Inherit&lt;/ShowColumnFooter&gt;&lt;ShowColumnFooterEachPage&gt;True&lt;/ShowColumnFooterEachPage&gt;&lt;ShowTitle&gt;True&lt;/ShowTitle&gt;&lt;ShowSubtitle&gt;True&lt;/ShowSubtitle&gt;&lt;UseMax&gt;True&lt;/UseMax&gt;&lt;UseSmartPrint&gt;False&lt;/UseSmartPrint&gt;&lt;Opacity&gt;255&lt;/Opacity&gt;&lt;PrintNotes&gt;None&lt;/PrintNotes&gt;&lt;Centering&gt;None&lt;/Centering&gt;&lt;RepeatColStart&gt;-1&lt;/RepeatColStart&gt;&lt;RepeatColEnd&gt;-1&lt;/RepeatColEnd&gt;&lt;RepeatRowStart&gt;-1&lt;/RepeatRowStart&gt;&lt;RepeatRowEnd&gt;-1&lt;/RepeatRowEnd&gt;&lt;SmartPrintPagesTall&gt;1&lt;/SmartPrintPagesTall&gt;&lt;SmartPrintPagesWide&gt;1&lt;/SmartPrintPagesWide&gt;&lt;HeaderHeight&gt;-1&lt;/HeaderHeight&gt;&lt;FooterHeight&gt;-1&lt;/FooterHeight&gt;&lt;/PrintInfo&gt;&lt;TitleInfo class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.TitleInfo&quot;&gt;&lt;Style class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.StyleInfo&quot;&gt;&lt;BackColor&gt;#e7eff7&lt;/BackColor&gt;&lt;HorizontalAlign&gt;Right&lt;/HorizontalAlign&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/TitleInfo&gt;&lt;LayoutTemplate class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.LayoutTemplate&quot;&gt;&lt;Layout&gt;&lt;ColumnCount&gt;4&lt;/ColumnCount&gt;&lt;RowCount&gt;1&lt;/RowCount&gt;&lt;/Layout&gt;&lt;Data&gt;&lt;LayoutData class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetDataModel&quot; rows=&quot;1&quot; columns=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;AutoCalculation&gt;True&lt;/AutoCalculation&gt;&lt;AutoGenerateColumns&gt;True&lt;/AutoGenerateColumns&gt;&lt;ReferenceStyle&gt;A1&lt;/ReferenceStyle&gt;&lt;Iteration&gt;False&lt;/Iteration&gt;&lt;MaximumIterations&gt;1&lt;/MaximumIterations&gt;&lt;MaximumChange&gt;0.001&lt;/MaximumChange&gt;&lt;Cells&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;0&quot; column=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.Int32&quot;&gt;0&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;0&quot; column=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.Int32&quot;&gt;1&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;0&quot; column=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.Int32&quot;&gt;2&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;Cell row=&quot;0&quot; column=&quot;3&quot;&gt;&lt;Data type=&quot;System.Int32&quot;&gt;3&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;&lt;/Cells&gt;&lt;/LayoutData&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;AxisModels&gt;&lt;LayoutColumn class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetAxisModel&quot; orientation=&quot;Horizontal&quot; count=&quot;4&quot;&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item index=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;&lt;SortIndicator&gt;Ascending&lt;/SortIndicator&gt;&lt;/Item&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/LayoutColumn&gt;&lt;LayoutRow class=&quot;FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.DefaultSheetAxisModel&quot; orientation=&quot;Vertical&quot; count=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Items&gt;&lt;Item index=&quot;-1&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Items&gt;&lt;/LayoutRow&gt;&lt;/AxisModels&gt;&lt;/LayoutTemplate&gt;&lt;LayoutMode&gt;CellLayoutMode&lt;/LayoutMode&gt;&lt;CurrentPageIndex type=&quot;System.Int32&quot;&gt;0&lt;/CurrentPageIndex&gt;&lt;/Settings&gt;&lt;/Sheet&gt;" 
            SheetName="Sheet1">
        </FarPoint:SheetView>
    </sheets>
        <ClientEvents DataChanged="dataChanged" EditStopped="dataChanged" />
    <TitleInfo BackColor="#E7EFF7" ForeColor="" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
        VerticalAlign="NotSet" Font-Size="X-Large" font-bold="False" 
        font-italic="False" font-overline="False" font-strikeout="False" 
        font-underline="False">
    </TitleInfo>
    </FarPoint:FpSpread>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="#0000CC" BorderColor="Red" 
        ForeColor="White" Height="16px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
</div>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var spread1 = document.getElementById("FpSpread1");
                  if (document.all) { 
                    // IE
                    if (spread1.addEventListener) {
                    // IE9
        //            spread1.addEventListener("DataChanged", dataChanged, false);     
                    spread1.addEventListener("DataChanged", function () {return dataChanged("FpSpread1","1")}, false);
                    } else {
                    // Other versions of IE and IE9 quirks mode (no doctype set)
                    spread1.onDataChanged = dataChanged("FpSpread1","1");
                    }
                    else {
                    // Firefox
        //            spread1.addEventListener("DataChanged", dataChanged, false);
                    spread1.addEventListener("DataChanged", function () {return dataChanged("FpSpread1","1")}, false);
                  } 
    }

    function dataChanged(elementID, combo) {
        var tb = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
        var s = document.getElementById(elementID);
        tb.value = v.value;
        tb.value = tb.value;
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't get this working in JavaScript so I used             `TextBox1.Text = FpSpread1.GetEditValue(row, col).ToString();` in the UpdateCommand event and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET server controls ids are not the client side (javascript) ids.

Also as to events, and everything.

All the  the `FarPoint:FpSpread` handling should happen in the C# (or VB?) code-behind.

It is possible to handle some events in JS but the server  control should support it somehow.

Read more about [asp.net controls](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_server_controls.htm)

Comment: Actually the DataChanged event has to be coded in JavaScript.

Comment: ok, look that the event name is "dataChanged" and not "DataChanged". and to capture the client id do:document.getElementById("<%= FpSpread1.ClientID %>");

Comment: and use JQuery ($("<%= FpSpread1.ClientID %>").on("dataChanged",function(){...}); to capture the events in one line of code instead of checking the browser